# Upload attachment from external site

Tags: posts, images, metabox, uploads, attachments

For example, we have some image on the external site:
http://site.com/image.png

How do I upload this image to my wordpress as an image attachment by php?

Image should be copied to my uploads folder, post added, meta generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `media_sideload_image()` function to upload your files ex:

`$upload = media_sideload_image( $url, $post_id );`

or you can use a plugin like [**Cache Images**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cache-images/) which uploads all external images to your server as attachments.